# Product Sigma Algebra of two sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Say I have two sigma algebras: $ \sigma(C) = \{E,\{\},\{1,2\},\{3,4,5\},\{1,2,3,4,5\},\{6\},\{3,4,5,6\},\{1,2,6\}\} $
where $E= \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

and $\sigma(Y) = \{E,\{\},\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\}\}$

How would one go about finding $\sigma(C) ⊗\sigma(Y) ?$

I know $\sigma(C) ⊗\sigma(Y) = \sigma(\{A\times B :  A\in \sigma(C) , B\in \sigma(Y)   \})$ is intuitively the smallest sigma algebra generated by the cartesian product.

Would this product algebra just give a set containing every tuple of sets from both sigma algebras eg: $(\{1,2\}\times\{1,3,5\})$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your second question:

These sets will belong to the product $\sigma$-algebra, but not every set in it will be such a set.

Realize that the *complement* of e.g. $\{1,2\}\times\{1,3,5\}$ is *not* a set that can be written as $A\times B$.

As you know $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complementation.

---

Answer to your first question:

In this special case there are partitions $\mathcal P=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4,5\},\{6\}\}$ and $\mathcal Q:=\{\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\}\}$ on set $E$. A set is element of the $\sigma(C)$  if and only if it can be written as a finite union of elements of $\mathcal P$. This union is also allowed to be empty. Likewise a set is element of the $\sigma(Y)$  if and only if it can be written as a finite union of elements of $\mathcal Q$.

This partition induces a partition $\mathcal R:=\mathcal P\times\mathcal Q=\{A\times B\mid A\in\mathcal P,B\in\mathcal Q\}$ on set $E\times E$, and a set is element of $\sigma(C)\otimes\sigma(Y)$ if it can be written as a finite union of elements of $\mathcal R$.

---

Note: because set $E$ is finite the class of algebras on it coincides with the class of $\sigma$-algebras on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why would the complement of {1,2}×{1,3,5} specifically not be in the joint sigma algebra? {3,4,5,6}x{2,4,6} is in σ(C)⊗σ(Y) no?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the complement of $\{1,2\}\times\{1,3,5\}$. E.g. it does not contain the element $(1,6)$.

Comment: Btw, I am not saying that the complement of $\{1,2\}\times\{1,3,5\}$ is not in the product topology. What I am saying is that the complement cannot be written as product of sets. So the collection $\{A\times B\mid A\in\sigma(C), B\in\sigma(Y)\}$ fails to be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I am struggling understanding what is the complement of $\{1,2\}\times\{1,3,5\}$. Is it \{1,2\}\times\{1,3,5\}$? Thank you

Comment: @Alchemy In general if $A\subseteq X,B\subseteq Y$ then the complement of: $$A\times B=\{(a,b)\in X\times Y\mid a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\}$$ in $X\times Y$ is the set: $$\{(a,b)\in X\times Y\mid a\notin A\text{ or }b\notin B\}$$ We can write as the union: $$(A^\complement\times Y)\cup(X\times B^\complement)$$In this situation we have $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1,3,5\}$ and $X=Y=E=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. So we end up with: $$(\{3,4,5,6\}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6\})\cup(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\times\{2,4,6\})$$Note that this not a square but is a union of two squares.